# Detect Snooker Billiard Balls

Tags: opencv

I am starting a project with OpenCV to accurately detect the position and contours of snooker balls (billiard balls).

These are the balls:[image: green billiard table with 15 billiard balls in a triangle, plus one white cue ball]

I've experimented with a few algorithms to no avail. This is what I've have done so far:

-**HoughCircles**: This barely works. Even adjusting parameters to millimeter resolution only results in a few balls detected, and the center of the balls are not accurately detected.

-**Canny**: Here I only can retrieve ball contours if the balls are not close to one another.

-**Threshold by color HSV**: Because the balls are not one color this just doesn't work.

I want to experiment with other algorithms like HaarCascadeDetection or SURF.

What you guys think?

Comment: The image does not display a snooker setup. Snooker balls usually have solid colors. Are you asking for another pool billiard setup?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% that it would work, but give it a try. I think if camera doesn't move, you can accoumplish this by means of fast fourier transform. Please take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem . What you should do:

1. I assume camera doesn't move
2. create a pattern image with a circle with same size as pic
3. make 2d fourier transform of image and pic
4. multiply transforms harmonix-by-harmonix
5. make inverse transform
6. find point that has highest intency

Comment: Yes, the camera doesn't move. But what happens when one player shows up in the image? Or the lights intensity changes?

Comment: Oh, in this case may be this is not very good solution. Then you should probably give more pictures, aren't you? I think you can improve my algorithm by extracting gradient from image first (so spots of balls would become circles and you should use not a spot pattern, but a circle pattern. I believe this problem is solvable this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option is to check whether to pixel color is in same range - use [inrange](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=inrange#inrange) function(note that it requires HSV image). Center of ball in this case is probably just a light reflection point(or somewhere very near to this point), which usually is the brightest point of the ball.

You may also try throwing out the table(threshold or inrange) and then analyzing all what is left.

Comment: I dont think that work. The balls have more than 1 color. Light reflection are 1 solution IF the balls didnt have more than 1 color, again.
I've tested your last solution but some balls are green like the table.

Answer (score 0):

I got some good results using just Hough circle transform (after playing with the parameters for awhile). I guess the trick is the combination of using a small enough param2 (to allow more detection) and restricting search radius (to filter out false positives).

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,5, 
            param1=100,param2=10,minRadius=6,maxRadius=10)
```

Also I removed the shadows, but I'm not sure if it's needed in your case.
Here's some test results.

[image]

[image]