# Image recognition: Detecting billiard balls on Android

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision, vuforia

I am trying to create an android app which can recognize Billiard balls on a pool table in an image coming from the camera. What would be the best approach to do this?

We can assume that the camera and the pool table are in fixed positions, but there could be object other than the balls on the pool table.

I am currently looking into two possible solutions:

1. Vuforia SDK - Simple API for object tracking / recognition, but I couldn't find any information about ball/sphere shape tracking. They have Cylinder and Image target that could possibly be used somehow to track the balls.
2. OpenCV - Seems much richer and steeper learning curve in comparison with Vuforia, but there is some information about Billiard ball detection online (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025192/detect-snooker-billiard-balls-with-opencv), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162234/detecting-billiard-balls-with-opencv)).

Are there any addition approaches for solving this problem? What would be the easiest working approach for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The balls are moving or not?
I've used SURF (and SFIT) they work great for arrested objects. Have a look to the [documentation page](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html) there are also two questions you should see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025192/detect-snooker-billiard-balls-with-opencv) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162234/detecting-billiard-balls-with-opencv). Than if you want to calculate the trajectory I've tried [Pymecavideo](http://outilsphysiques.tuxfamily.org/pmwiki.php/Oppl/Pymecavideo) that uses OpenCv maybe a look into the source code could be interesting for your work.

Comment: Thanks G M, the balls are not moving, I just take a shot of the table and want to figure out where the balls are. I have looked in the documentation page for SURF and SFIT, and they seems to be a part of the Nonfree package of OpenCV (patented or something like that), so it's complicated to get them on Android, though possible. Will have a look in Pymecavideo as well...

Comment: Can you post a test image? If the balls are not moving maybe you can use [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) with some implementation....

Comment: Many thanks G.M, I will definitely have a look into this. As for a test image, this should look more or less like the following one:

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/US_Navy_050315-N-2385R-009_Ship%27s_Serviceman_2nd_Class_Neil_Mendoza_assigned_to_Transient_Personnel_Detachment_%28TPD%29_on_board_U.S._Fleet_Activities_Sasebo,_Japan,_lines_up_his_shot_during_a_game_of_pool.jpg

Comment: Is very difficult with not perpendicular images, is hard to use template matching with scalable objects so I would try a different approach. I would take a snapshot without balls select the blue area by color (blue), this will be the working area to exclude the players. You can subtract the background ‘if pixelonlybackground==pixelwithballs, you perform some sort of particles analysis to obtain a mask calculate the mean color of the particle and see if you can identify the ball.  I think you should calibrate your system first.

Comment: Thanks G M, Do you have a good reference about the particle analysis? Is this something OpenCV would be good at?

Comment: I've always use it compiled in Fiji(ImageJ) I never try to do it on my own but with OpenCV maybe I will try [this](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/) I hope it works. If you performa a background subtracting remember to maintain fixed the camera's parameters (e.g. ISO) take a look to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CigGvt3DXIw) too, code is posted below.